# How can I use xforms:load to embed a javascript in an xforms page and then call it?

Tags: orbeon, xforms, xsltforms, xforms-betterform

I know we call invoke a JavaScript method using `xf:load` in the `xforms-ready` event of the model.

```
<xf:load resource="javascript:myFunction()" />
```

But how can I embed JavaScript? I.e. I want to dynamically generate javascript from a resource, embed it in an element and then invoke it using the method above?

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing XForms "by hand", you can include your own JavaScript by adding a `<script>` inside the `<head>` of your page. There is really nothing specific to XForms here. With Orbeon Forms, you would typically use the `xh` prefix to denote this is something from HTML:

```
<xh:script src="/path/to/your/script.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

If you're using Form Builder to create the form, then you'll want to use the `oxf.fr.js.custom.uri.*.*` property to [reference JavaScript files to include](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner.html#adding-your-own-javascript).